# Can't access broadcast variable in transformation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, broadcast

I'm having problems accessing a variable from inside a transformation function.  Could someone help me out?
Here are my relevant classes and functions.

```
@SerialVersionUID(889949215L)
object MyCache extends Serializable {
    @transient lazy val logger = Logger(getClass.getName)
    @volatile var cache: Broadcast[Map[UUID, Definition]] = null

    def getInstance(sparkContext: SparkContext) : Broadcast[Map[UUID, Definition]] = {
        if (cache == null) {
            synchronized {
                val map = sparkContext.cassandraTable("keyspace", "table")
                   .collect()
                   .map(m => m.getUUID("id") ->
                        Definition(m.getString("c1"), m.getString("c2"), m.getString("c3"),
                                m.getString("c4"))).toMap
                cache = sparkContext.broadcast(map)
            }
        }
        cache
    }
}
```

In a different file:

```
object Processor extends Serializable {
    @transient lazy val logger = Logger(getClass.getName)

    def processData[T: ClassTag](rawStream: DStream[(String, String)], ssc: StreamingContext,
                                        processor: (String, Broadcast[Map[UUID, Definition]]) => T): DStream[T] = {
        MYCache.getInstance(ssc.sparkContext)
        var newCacheValues = Map[UUID, Definition]()
        rawStream.cache()
        rawStream
          .transform(rdd => {
                val array = rdd.collect()
                array.foreach(r => {
                      val value = getNewCacheValue(r._2, rdd.context)
                      if (value.isDefined) {
                          newCacheValues = newCacheValues + value.get
                      }
                })
                rdd
           })
       if (newCacheValues.nonEmpty) {
           logger.info(s"Rebroadcasting.  There are ${newCacheValues.size} new values")
           logger.info("Destroying old cache")
           MyCache.cache.destroy()
           // this is probably wrong here, destroying object, but then referencing it.  But I haven't gotten to this part yet.
           MyCache.cache = ssc.sparkContext.broadcast(MyCache.cache.value ++ newCacheValues)
       }
       rawStream
          .map(r => {
               println("######################")
               println(MyCache.cache.value)
               r
          })
          .map(r => processor(r._2, MyCache.cache.value))
          .filter(r => null != r)
   }
}
```

Every time I run this I get `SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_1_piece0 of broadcast_1` when trying to access cache.value

When I add a `println(MyCache.cache.values)` right after the `.getInstance` I'm able to access the broadcast variable, but when I deploy it to a mesos cluster I'm unable to access the broadcast values again, but with a null pointer exception.

**Update:**

The error I'm seeing is on `println(MyCache.cache.value)`.  I shouldn't have added this if statement containing the destroy, because my tests are never hitting that.

The basics of my application are, I have a table in cassandra that won't be updated very much.  But I need to do some validation on some streaming data.  So I want to pull all the data from this table, that isn't update much, into memory.  `getInstance` pulls the whole table in on startup, and then I check all my streaming data to see if I need to pull from cassandra again (which I will have to very rarely).  The transform and collect is where I check to see if I need to pull new data in.  But since there is a chance that my table will be updated, I will need to update the broadcast occasionally.  So my idea was to destroy it and then rebroadcast.  I will update that once I get the other stuff working.

I get the same error if I comment out the destroy and rebroadcast.

**Another update:**

I need to access the broadcast variable in `processor` this line: `.map(r => processor(r._2, MyCache.cache.value))`.

I'm able to broadcast variable in the transform, and if I do `println(MyCache.cache.value)` in the transform, then all my tests pass, and I'm able to then access the broadcast in `processor`

**Update:**

```
rawStream
    .map(r => {
      println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$")
      println(metrics.value)
      r
    })
```

This is the stack trace I get when it hits this line.

```
    ERROR org.apache.spark.executor.Executor - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 135.0 (TID 114)
    java.io.IOException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_1_piece0 of broadcast_1
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1222)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.readBroadcastBlock(TorrentBroadcast.scala:165)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value$lzycompute(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.getValue(TorrentBroadcast.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast.value(Broadcast.scala:70)
        at com.uptake.readings.ingestion.StreamProcessors$$anonfun$processIncomingKafkaData$4.apply(StreamProcessors.scala:160)
        at com.uptake.readings.ingestion.StreamProcessors$$anonfun$processIncomingKafkaData$4.apply(StreamProcessors.scala:158)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:370)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:370)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:414)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.unrollSafely(MemoryStore.scala:284)
        at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.putInBlockManager(CacheManager.scala:171)
        at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:268)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_1_piece0 of broadcast_1
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:138)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:138)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply$mcVI$sp(TorrentBroadcast.scala:137)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:120)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:175)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1219)
        ... 24 more
```

Comment: Which line is the error on? It looks like the one you even commented "this is probably wrong", because it's the first access of `MyCache.cache.value` and it shouldn't work. Calling `rdd.collect()` inside `transform` also seems strange to me.

Comment: It looks to me like you are on a wrong path here. Broadcasting is intended for distributing something static (like an immutable map) to all workers for quick access. From the looks of it, you are trying to _build up_ the map and you should not use broadcast for that. And I agree with @Alexey Romanov that calling `rdd.collect` seems very odd, as the whole rdd is then processed on the driver rather than in parallel, and parallel processing is kind of what Spark excels at...

Comment: Oops, sorry I'll add an update to my question.  I didn't give very much context here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Updated answer]

You're getting an error because the code inside `rawStream.map` i.e. `MyCache.cache.value` is getting executed on one of the executor and there the MyCache.cache is still `null`!

When you did `MyCache.getInstance`, it created the `MyCache.cache` value *on the driver* and broadcasted it alright. But you're not referring to the same object in the your `map` method, so it doesn't get sent over to executors. Instead since you are directly referring to the `MyCache`, the executors invoke `MyCache.cache` on their own copy of `MyCache` object, and this obviously is null.

You can get this to work as expected by first getting an instance of `cache` broadcast object within the driver and using *that* object in the map. The following code should work for you --

```
val cache = MYCache.getInstance(ssc.sparkContext)
rawStream.map(r => {
                     println(cache.value)
                     r
             })
```

Comment: Oops, sorry I didn't give very much context, let me update my question.

Comment: I think I can see the issue now. (I am new to Stackoverflow. Not sure what the accepted procedure to update an answer is -- but I will update the original answer.)

Comment: Cool thanks.  That makes a lot of sense.  But then how can I reference this in other files?  I thought that adding it as property on this static class would do the same thing?  That way I don't have to pass it to every function I want to refer to it in.

Comment: Within the driver itself, you can still always invoke `val cache = MYCache.getInstance(ssc.sparkContext)` from any-where/file . Just make sure that whenever there's some code to be executed on executors, you pass the actual broadcast object and not just the static method call.

Comment: Oooh that makes a lot of sense.  I'll try it out, and the come back and accept this answer if it works.   Thanks!

Comment: So I added `val metrics = MetricsCache.getInstance(ssc.sparkContext)` to the top of `def processData` and then I was able to reference it in the first map, but when I passed it to `.map(r => processor(r._2, metrics))` I'm still having issues referencing it.

Comment: Can you please update the exact error and stacktrace?

Comment: Thanks.

1) I tested my reasoning for the answer above and it's correct. I m able to reproduce a Nullpointer exception as expected. (Even though you didnt mention it -- according to my understanding you should also have got the NPE earlier b4 making the changes I mentioned.)

2) However, your issue is not NPE. But some problem with broadcast fetch on executor. Just looked at the code and cause is not immediately clear. 

Then came across this exact same [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5594) that's been open for some time now. Might spend some time tomorrow on it.

Comment: I did actually mention a null point exception up above.  I'm not getting the npe locally, but I get it when it gets to higher environments.

Comment: Ahh, right. Yeah, so basically we solved the NPE issue but now stuck on the missing broadcast piece thingy. I do not have immediate answer for that -- it will probably require some investigation. In the meantime you can try setting `spark.broadcast.factory` to `org.apache.spark.broadcast.HttpBroadcastFactory`. Apparently `HttpBroadcast` seems to work fine in cases of such a bug for `TorrentBroadcast`.

Comment: Alright, thanks.  That link isn't loading for me right now but when I get the chance I'll try out HttpBroadcast